# Firebase Storage "Permission denied" error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I try to read my Firebase Storage data I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
  }
}
```

But my rules are set to public:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Here's my code:

```
export const getAll = async () => {
    let list: Photo[] = [];

    const imagesFolder = ref(storage, "images");
    const photoList = await listAll(imagesFolder);

    for(let i in photoList.items) {
        let photoUrl = await getDownloadURL(photoList.items[i]);

        list.push({
            name: photoList.items[i].name,
            url: photoUrl
        });
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: sometime it is caused  because your object (or all bucket) is under active Event-Based hold and cannot be deleted [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/holding-objects#set-default-hold]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the steps in this post fixed my issue:

This is due to a missing permission:

```
firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com
```

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Select your project in the top blue bar
3. Scroll down the left menu and select "Cloud Storage"
4. Select all your buckets then click "ADD PRINCIPAL" on the right
5. Add "firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com" and "Storage
   Admin" as a role
6. Save it

https://newbedev.com/firebase-storage-security-rules-400-error-issue-permission-denied-could-not-access-bucket-xxxxx-appspot-com

Answer (score 0):

Before you setting for storage admin, make sure you have activate your google cloud platform. Because it's can be the first cause, if you use firebase storage and you never use google cloud platform before